# How can I reference other sheets by column value?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

This is the scenario:

```
Sheet1:

A      B
name   age
Jack   40
Alice  50
Bob    60

Sheet2:
A        B
item     Jack
Sheet1   40 <- use formula here
```

In Sheet2, A column has the sheet name (e.g. 'Sheet1') and row 0 has the name (e.g.'Jack'), I would like get 40 in B2 cell with a formula! Just like query from Sheet1 with name Jack and get the age value!

BTW, Sheet1 and Jack is variable, maybe changed so Sheet1!A1 syntax will not good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B1, INDIRECT(A2&"A:B"), 2, 0))
```

where B1 is your `Jack` and A2 is your `Sheet1`

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. one more question is how to list all duplicated items in the same cell?

Comment: @beetlej not sure what do you mean. can you share a copy of your sheet with example?

Comment: Sorry for confuse, I just mean if I have multiple line in Sheet1 as Jack 40 and Jack 50, then I would like to see 40 and 50 in the output, then I know duplicate item happened!

Comment: @beetlej in that case try: `=JOIN(", ", FILTER(INDIRECT(A2&"B:B"), INDIRECT(A2&"A:A")=B1)`